# Continuous function of bounded variation

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, geometric-measure-theory

Let $f$ be a continuous function with bounded variation on $[0,1]$.

Question: Is it true that 
\begin{equation*}
\int_{[0,1]}f'(x)dx=f(1)-f(0) ?
\end{equation*}

Comment: Hint: consider a step function.

Comment: Would you happy with an affirmative answer for $f$ Lipschitz continuous? I can give you an argument (using martingales) in that case. Maybe it can be adapted.

Comment: I think we need absolute continuity rather than just continuity here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is false. The Cantor function is continuous, increasing (and so it has bounded variation) and $f'(x)=0$ for $\mathcal{L}^1$ a.e. $x\in [0,1]$, so
$$f(1)-f(0)=1-0>\int_0^1 f'(x)\,dx=0.$$
For the fundamental theorem of calculus to hold it is necessary and sufficient that $f$ is absolutely continuous.

Comment: Can I just consider step function $f(x)=1$ for $x \in [0,1/2]$ and $f=0$ for $x \in (1/2,1]?$

Comment: The question asks for a continuous function of bounded variation. A step function is discontinuous so the fundamental theorem of calculus fails easily